# Indexing and Slicing of matrices in python

Tags: python, slice

```
 import numpy as np  
A= array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
              [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
              [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
              [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
              [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
              [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56],
              [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]])
```

I want to grab (0,4,5,7) row and col in this order
so o/p will look like

```
A=                                                                                       
    1    5    4    8
   33   37   36   40
   25   29   28   32
   57   61   60   64
```

I tried this A[(0,4,5,7),(0,4,5,7)] but it's giving me error.

Note: I want to slice it in the same matrix.

Comment: Wait, can you clarify how you reached that output using that matrix and numbers?

Comment: Grab the 0,4,5,7 row  and save it in a matrix
it'll look like this
>>> b=a[[0,4,3,7],]
>>> b
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
       [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]])
then grab (0,4,3,7) col in other var
>>> c=b[:,[0,4,3,7]]
>>> c
array([[ 1,  5,  4,  8],
       [33, 37, 36, 40],
       [25, 29, 28, 32],
       [57, 61, 60, 64]])

Comment: Since you show the `array` construct in  your question, are you using numpy?

Comment: Seems reasonable to believe so, @RoryDaulton, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: @YotamSalmon: Probably, but the OP should say so in the question or the tags, and numpy's is not the only `array` construct in Python.

Comment: Yoss numpy, I got the answer
Thanks guys
A[[0,4,5,7],:][:,[0,4,5,7]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out in your last comment, you can also use Numpy [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
J = np.repeat([[0,4,3,7]], 4, axis=0)
B = A[J.T, J]
>>> B
array([[ 1,  5,  4,  8],
       [33, 37, 36, 40],
       [25, 29, 28, 32],
       [57, 61, 60, 64]])
```

Comment: OMG! 
You're life saver dude
thank you from bottom of my heart
`x = A[:,[0,4,5,7]]
x = x[[0,4,5,7],:]

>>> x
array([[ 1,  5,  6,  8],
       [33, 37, 38, 40],
       [41, 45, 46, 48],
       [57, 61, 62, 64]])`
this worked too but it's not broadcasting

Answer (score 2):

You can index in 2 steps

```
x = A[:,[0,4,5,7]]
x = x[[0,4,5,7],:]

>>> x
array([[ 1,  5,  6,  8],
       [33, 37, 38, 40],
       [41, 45, 46, 48],
       [57, 61, 62, 64]])
```

I changed the variable names so that you keep the original `A`, but you don't have to do that if you don't want to.

Or, in one line:

```
x = A[:,[0,4,5,7]][[0,4,5,7],:]
```

Comment: I see, Thanks Senpai :) Darn it!
A[:,[0,4,5,7]][[0,4,5,7],:]
I didn't get your exp tho but It helped, I wrote It like A[[0,4,5,7],:][:,[0,4,5,7]] 
BTW whats the difference?

Comment: That's very strange; both of those give me the same output (as they should). The difference is that in mine, I am indexing columns first and then rows, but you index rows first and then columns. But as long as it works, doesn't matter!

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, but I couldn't understand
"I am indexing columns first and then rows, but you index rows first and then columns" Oh, didn't know one could do that xD